# Removing certain lines/vectors from map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, vector, editing

It has been a while since I have done anything but basic work with GIS.

I have a map with a utility system, comprised of points and lines. I wish to create a map with only a select few of these lines.

Is there any easy way to copy the vectors and nodes I want, and copy them to a new layer or shapefile, or to mass delete the one I do not want?

[image: Map Example]

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options.  If you already have the lines selected then right click the layer in the table of contents, choose Selection, and choose Create Layer From Selected Features.  This will create an in-memory representation of your selected features.  Then, turn off the original data.

If you do not have the lines selected then you could select them manually-if there was only a few lines,-or write a definition query to only display lines that have some common attributes.

You probably want to avoid do a mass delete since this kind of change to the data would result in a permanent loss.

Comment: In addition to this, once you create a new layer from selected features be sure to export that layer to a new shapefile/feature class then import the newly created shapefile/feature class

Comment: I would try to use a definition query.

Comment: I will try the selection to a new layer. (there are a decent amount of lines but not a ton). Thank you for the help